# Debian: where are services installed

Tags: service, debian, debian-stretch

I want edit raspberrypi-net-mods.service to copy a file, rather than move it.

How would I go about locating this please?

Answer (score 1):

YOu can get the location of a systemd-unit via

```
systemctl status raspberrypi-net-mods.service
```

You shouldn't edit system-installed service-files directly.
Instead you can *customize* a service by adding configuration to `/etc/systemd/system/`

You probably want to read the documentation, e.g. [man 5 systemd.unit](https://www.google.com/search?q=systemd+extend+service+file)